# adding mediaplayer in non activity class

Tags: android, class, nullpointerexception, android-mediaplayer

ı have two classes in my simple android game:   myBaseObject, myMissile...   ı want to add a sound myMissile class with Mediaplayer.

```
public class myBaseObject {
    MediaPlayer shoot;
    Context context;

    // ...

    public void myShoot()
    {
        shoot = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.laser_effect);
        shoot.setVolume(100,100);       
        shoot.start();
    }
}


// .......

public class myMissile extends myBaseObject {


    public Missile( Bitmap bitmap, float x, float y, double velocity,
        double direction) {

        //...

        myShoot();
    }

}
```

after starting game with activity class, ı see a NullPointerException on mediaplayer .. and game crashes...  how can ı solve this problem?  ı tried very much ways..  but i couldnt solve..

this is my LogCat 
02-02 12:37:43.496: E/AndroidRuntime(15009): at com.mycorp.myapp.myMissile.(myMissile.java:41)

02-02 12:37:43.496: E/AndroidRuntime(15009): at com.mycorp.myapp.MissileHandler.update(MissileHandler.java:75)

02-02 12:37:43.496: E/AndroidRuntime(15009): at com.mycorp.myapp.GameEngine.update(GameEngine.java:159)

02-02 12:37:43.496: E/AndroidRuntime(15009): at com.mycorp.myapp.GameThread.run(GameThread.java:51)

02-02 12:38:32.811: I/Process(15009): Sending signal. PID: 15009 SIG: 9

Comment: Include your logcat in your question

Comment: you dont get context in a non activity class

Answer (score 0):

As per your question its clear that you are not passing your activity context. that why it give you nullpointer exception.

modify your code like beloe can help you

```
public class myBaseObject {
    MediaPlayer shoot;
    Context context;

     public void myShoot(Context ctx){
            this.context = ctx;
            shoot = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.laser_effect);

            shoot.setVolume(100,100);

            shoot.start();

            }
}

public class myMissile extends myBaseObject {

//Context ctx
  public Missile( Bitmap bitmap, float x, float y, double velocity,
    double direction) {
.
.
.


   myShoot(this);

  }
```

Comment: thanks for help.. but it didnt solve.. this is my LogCat

02-02 12:37:43.496: E/AndroidRuntime(15009):  at com.mycorp.myapp.myMissile.<init>(myMissile.java:41)

02-02 12:37:43.496: E/AndroidRuntime(15009):  at com.mycorp.myapp.MissileHandler.update(MissileHandler.java:75)

02-02 12:37:43.496: E/AndroidRuntime(15009):  at com.mycorp.myapp.GameEngine.update(GameEngine.java:159)

02-02 12:37:43.496: E/AndroidRuntime(15009):  at com.mycorp.myapp.GameThread.run(GameThread.java:51)

02-02 12:38:32.811: I/Process(15009): Sending signal. PID: 15009 SIG: 9